# Configurar reglas de firestore para que no sean inseguras

Tags: android, firebase, seguridad, firestore

Tengo una app sin registro de usuarios que se basa en recoger datos de una API y guardarlos en Firestore para que puedan ser consultadas posteriormente sin tener que volver a acceder a la API.

El problema es que estos usuarios no se registran, y por lo tanto, no puedo preguntar en la configuración de reglas si el que lee o el que escribe es un usuario registrado.

Mi pregunta es, se podrían llegar a configurar unas reglas que dijeran que solo se puede leer o escribir si el origen es una app o algo parecido para que éstas no fueran inseguras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede iniciar sesión de forma anónima en Firebase de esta manera

En Flutter:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

En Java:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

Luego, puede configurar sus reglas de Cloud Firebase para mostrar que el origen del uso es su aplicación así

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
   }
}
```